# Only load script on specific page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using a script that checks how much checkboxes you selected and that limits it to 4 checkboxes.

The script is loaded in in the footer of my page (seperate file, called footer.php)

The script is of course called in every file, because the footer is selected in every file. Is is it possible with some sort of function that it only uses that part of the script in a certain file, and not in EVERY file?

I am not even sure if it matters. My application is very small, so I think it's not a big point if I don't do the check, but I think it is better to use some sort of script.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, I would strongly recommend that you take a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works and what kind of questions are appropriate here. Your question is currently off-topic for the site.

Comment: why not take it out of the footer and only load the script on the pages you need it

Comment: Yes, that's possible: determine the proper condition under which the script should be loaded, implement it. If you are stuggling with that, post your exact problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if(location.href === 'https://example.com/donotrunhere') throw new Error('This is not an error. This is just to abort javascript');

// or wrap your code to the function

(function() {
  if(location.href === 'https://example.com/donotrunhere')
    return
    
  // your code here
  alert("hi")


})()
```